Possible actions vs Gaining of ability
Which one refers to a possible action that can taken and which one refers to the gaining of a future ability?
I made up these two sentences so there’s no source. I know they are not interchangeable and totally different, but I just want to know what they sound like.

If they run away, we can intercept them on their way

If they run away, we’ll be able to intercept them on their way.


PS: They are not the same so please don’t tell me they are. We must distinguish between them.

I'm sorry, but to me they do both mean the same. Yes, 'we will be able to' can mean that we will gain the ability in the future, but in this context it just means 'we will have that ability in a hypothetical future in which 'they' have run away'.

@KateBunting Thanks for replying. Let's see what others think about it.

@KateBunting is right. To this American, your two sentences are both perfectly acceptable and also essentially identical in meaning.

So the first one doesn't sound more like presenting a possible action that can be taken?

Since we have both told you that the two sentences mean the same, obviously we don't think it does!

@KateBunting that’s weird because it obviously sounds so.

"Obviousness" is a subjective thing.

@MichaelHarvey What do you think about the difference between these two sentences?

"Chien Te Lu" (or perhaps should I say "jasonlu2000") - definitely no difference in meaning.

The bolded bit in this phrase "intercept them on their way". is what sounds weird.



If they run away, we can intercept them on their way.
If they run away, we’ll be able to intercept them on their way.


Edit 2
As commented by fellow users, examples (1) and (2) are the same.
If they run away, we’ll have that ability to intercept them on their way.
Original Answer
(1) refers to a possible action that can be taken.
Though we'll be able to has the sense of gaining ability, it can't apply here as our ability to intercept the escapees doesn't rely on the act of the escape.  Hence only the first sentence makes sense.

The second one implies the gaining of ability, and yes, you are right. “If they run away, we’ll be able to intercept them” is not really logically correct. The gaining of ability to intercept doesn’t rely on their escape. Is this what you feel about sentence 2, that it implies the gaining of ability but doesn’t make much sense?

Yes, we'll be able to means gaining ability, but it just can't apply here as I've explained.

yeah that’s why I think maybe example 1 is the only sentence that makes sense out of the two.

Yes.  I've added these points to my answer.

Thank you for replying so fast. Are you a native speaker of American English?

I see. You are from Singapore.

I think you are trying very hard to see a 'difference' where there isn't one.

I agree with those who say there is no difference. (And I am an experienced native English speaker.) To me, they are two different wordings of the idea that "If they run away, we will have an opportunity to intercept them."

Thanks, @Peter Kirkpatrick and fellow users for your comments.  I have edited my answer.

@SeowjoohengSingapore I don't think your second edit is necessary.
